# Select elements from attributes, with unknown value after colons

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, css-selectors

everyone, I was looking for a way to select HTML elements such as:

```
<div attr:something="else">Random content</div>
```

I found that you could select this  using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attr\\3A something]')
```

But, my problem is **How can you select these like**:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attr\\3A *]')
```

So, if you replace `:something` by `:else`, you should still get the same element.

*The problem originally comes from an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/arguiot/DisplayJS/issues/37), which I found interesting, but I couldn't find another way of doing this:*

> **Adding ability for var to assign to attributes?**
>   I mean something like this:
>   `<a var:href="url"></a>`,
>   so that the `url` variable gets assigned to the `href` attribute.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings, this says you can use limited dataset in attribute selector with regex. `\\3A` can be raplaced with `\\:` which also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match attribute names with wildcards, even if they have a common namespace prefix.